# Android systrace descheduled frame

Tags: android, performance, systrace

I'm running systrace on my application to identify problems. One of my cases issues a warning in the systrace report html:

> Work to produce this frame was descheduled for several milliseconds, contributing to jank. Ensure that code on the UI thread doesn't block on work being done on other threads, and that background threads (doing e.g. network or bitmap loading) are running at android.os.Process#THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND or lower so they are less likely to interrupt the UI thread. These background threads should show up with a priority number of 130 or higher in the scheduling section under the Kernel process.

I understand the warning, but I cannot see any reason why this is happening in my trace report. Below I've attached the frame in question, are there any information there as to what is causing this problem?

[image: Systrace frame]

Comment: You need to look at the CPU core rows, which show what is running on each core at any given time.